# Why I can't put all desired styles under the same group while in an css file (VSCode)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have to keep on writing say:

```
p {
color: red
}
p {
padding: 30px
}
```

instead of just

```
p {
color: red
padding: 30px
}
```

[html file with the href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YEGY.png)

[Please check line 9, where the attribute is not accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdx6x.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add semicolons to your css for the first example to be valid.

> A semicolon ( ; ) is required after a property:value pair in a CSS
>   style.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93t4wab3(v=vs.71).aspx

```css
p {
color: red;
padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>testing</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all the link to the stylesheet should be in head tag, and secondly you should add a ; after every attribute : value in css, so it should be like

```
p {
  color: red;
  padding: 30px;
}
```